# How to make a Jmeter report from several files (jtl, png)

Tags: jmeter

I need to create an html report after the completing jmeter test and send it to the email. I launch jmeter via console with creating jtl log file, then I transfering it to html with

```
xsltproc /path/to/jmeter-results-detail.xsl $jtl > results.html
```

but I also have several images, which I generated from jtl file.

```
java -jar CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-png test.png --input-jtl results.jtl --plugin-type ResponseTimesOverTime --width 800 --height 600
```

So I would like to include them in this report. Shall I change the xsl file? The file is here: http://pastebin.com/rJE4ivz8

And one more, all the information about xml->html I took from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11191109/2042311 but in this template there is a date of the test, but in my html file I don't have this field.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to use the default HTML report that is available since version 3.0 of JMeter and keeps being enriched.

To generate it just run:

> jmeter -n -t TestName.jmx -l results.csv -e -o reportOutputFolder

You can also generate it from existing CSV:

> jmeter -g results.csv -o reportOutputFolder

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html